# How to change selection of richtextbox from another form in C#?

Tags: c#, parent-child, richtextbox, notepad

I am trying to implement Notepad application clone in C#. Now I have a smaller problem in implementation. In a notepad application for implementing find next option, I created a new form which will have a reference to the main form. When Find Next button is clicked on the find form, I will use the richtextbox content in the mainform, current cursor position,direction of search, search string and matchcase to calculate selectionstart for the richtextbox and then update the selection. Now the calculation of selectionstart is working fine. I can get the length of selection from the search string and set selection. I am trying to set selection on the main form by using the reference I passed to the find form. When I do that, richtextbox won't highlight unless I BringToFront the mainForm or close the find form window. So my question is how to achieve selection of contents of richtextbox from another form(child form) just as implemented in windows notepad?

[image: Windows Notepad]

**Code snippets:**

**FormFind.cs**

```
private void btnFindNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        qry.SearchString = txtFind.Text;
        qry.Direction = oUp.Checked ? "UP" : "DOWN";
        qry.MatchCase = chkMatchCase.Checked ? true : false;
        qry.Content = mainForm.GetContent();
        qry.Position = mainForm.GetCurrentCursorPosition();

        FindNextResult result=editOperation.FindNext(qry);
        if (result.SearchStatus)
            mainForm.SetSelection(result.SelectionStart,
                txtFind.Text.Length); 
    }
```

**MainForm.cs**

```
private void findEditMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (formFind == null)
        formFind = new FormFind(this);
      formFind.Show();
   }

public string GetContent()
    {
        return txtArea.Text.ToString();
    }

internal void SetSelection(int selectionStart, int length)
    {
        txtArea.SelectionStart=selectionStart;
        txtArea.SelectionLength = length;
        this.BringToFront();
    }

internal int GetCurrentCursorPosition()
    {
        return txtArea.SelectionStart;
    }
```

Comment: [RichTextBox.HideSelection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.hideselection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Just to add a (unsolicited) suggestion. Since all the operation will actually be performed by `FormFind` and its controls, why don't you pass it a reference to the `MainForm` RichTextBox so you can elaborate those methods in one place (e.g. `qry.Content = mainForm.GetContent()` would simply be `Editor.Text`)?. With a public property in `FindForm`, you could:  `FormFind formFind = new FormFind(); formFind.Editor = this.richTextBox1; formFind.Show(this);` So that you don't have to go back and forth if you have something to change/add.

Comment: @SirRufo It works but brings the form to the front. So I did as Jimi suggested to add a property. RichTextBox.HideSelection will make sure the text is highlighted. and adding property helps to change everything from formFind itself. Thanks both of you, for your help :)

Comment: In FormFind's constructor: TopMost = true;

Comment: You just need `RichTextBox.HideSelection = false` and get rid of  `MainForm.BringToFront();` Since you have `formFind.Show(this)`, the user can interact with the editor, like Notepad does..

Comment: @Jimi Yeah I added it for testing things. Now with editor, everything is working as expected. Thank you for your help.